# Xploder Minecraft Diamond Edition doesn't detect players

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

My little sister bought the Xploder Minecraft Diamond Edition and we are really annoyed at the lack of help given when setting it up. We've tried all week to set up the software. Recently it came to my attention that the software is not detecting the player. This means we cannot save any maps.

We've checked that the USB stick is not the problem nor the player files.

Is there a way to make the players show up? They are definitely saved onto the USB stick.

Comment: The Amazon reviews for this product suggest that practically no one has gotten it to work...